# Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding error in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

```
quadraticRoots :: Floating t => t -> t -> t -> (t, t)
quadraticRoots a b c = if d < 0 then error "0" else (x, y)
                          where
                            x = e + sqrt d / (2 * a)
                            y = e - sqrt d / (2 * a)
                            d = b * b - 4 * a * c
                            e = - b / (2 * a)
```

The above code gives the following error in Hugs:

```
Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding
*** Expression    : quadraticRoots
*** Type          : Floating a => a -> a -> a -> (a,a)
*** Given context : Floating a
*** Constraints   : Ord a
```

Can anyone help me interpret this?

Answer (score 4):

In order to make a comparison like `d < 0`, the thing you are comparing must be a member of the `Ord` typeclass. Thus, we need to amend our type signature to include the additional constraint `Ord`:

```
quadraticRoots :: (Ord t, Floating t) => t -> t -> t -> (t, t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your type signature says `t` is in `Floating` type class, but compiler found it must also be in `Ord`.

Were `Ord` a [superclass](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html) of `Floating`, all would be good. But it's not.

To see the type the compiler derives ([*infers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference)), just omit the explicit type signature. Then, after defining the function in GHCi, ask

```
~> :t quadraticRoots
quadraticRoots :: (Ord t, Floating t) => t -> t -> t -> (t, t)
```

`<` is in `Ord`, `sqrt` is in `Floating`, and `/` is in `Fractional`. But `Floating` is a subclass of `Fractional`, so specifying it alone is enough for the both of them:

```
~> :i sqrt
class Fractional a => Floating a where
  ...
  sqrt :: a -> a
  ...

~> :i /
class Num a => Fractional a where
  (/) :: a -> a -> a
  ...
infixl 7 /

~> :i <
class Eq a => Ord a where
  ...
  (<) :: a -> a -> Bool
  ...
infix 4 <
```